# First-child changes multiple nested divs CSS

Tags: html, css

I am having some problem with the first-child and nth-child function in CSS. I have some divs structured like this:

```
<div class = container>
  <div id = 456, class = item>
     <div id = header_123, class = item_header>
        <div class = text_container>
          <div class="header_span">This is Item 456</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id = 789, class = item>
     <div id = header_124, class = item_header>
        <div class = text_container>
          <div class="header_span">This is Item 789</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id = 123, class = item>
     <div id = header_125, class = item_header>
        <div class = text_container>
          <div class="header_span">This is Item 123</div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the left-margin of the first div with class item. I use

```
.item div:first-child{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

This changes the div with id 456's margin, but also the margin of all the text_container and header_span. This is not what I want; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `first-of-class` selector which is what you seem to be asking for.

Comment: you can try it : - http://jsfiddle.net/Khumesh/4w8q752e/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the immediate child selector `>`:

```
.item > div:first-child {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

**Note:** And I could see that you are not wrapping your attributes inside `"` and also an `id` cannot start with a number.

> I want to change the left-margin of the first div with class item.

If that's the case, you need to use:

```
div.item:first-child {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

But that gives totally a different one.

Comment: Grr... Why are you so fast in commenting! `:P`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! The divs I wrote here are just examples so I did not think them through much, but ofcourse you're right.

Comment: @e.klara.k Glad it helped. `:)`

Comment: Just one little addition, from HTML5 IDs may start with a number: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.id But @PraveenKumar is totally correct: the html provided in the question is invalid nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
.item:first-child{
    margin-left: 30px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html has few mistakes, Try to fix it like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bnmj0nd3/1/)**

- Wrap `class` and `id` with `" "`
- Remove `div's` that have `,` in between `id` and `class`

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="456" class="item">
        <div id="header_123" class="item_header">
            <div class="text_container">
                <div class="header_span">This is Item 456</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  ...
```

CSS:

```
.item:first-child {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

As Sanjay and Praveen mentioned you need to use `:first-child` pseudo-class